# displaying image from xml file using xslt (offline)

Tags: xml, image, xslt, local

So, I'm trying to make my page display an image of every world wonder in the "History" section before the description of the image. Attached are my XML files, my XSLT and my output file. All images are stored locally in the same directory as my XML and XSLT files. At the bottom of XML file is of the images that I want to display. At the bottom of the XSLT file, starting with, <xsl:template match="main_image"> is the beginning of my attempt to display my image. I don't get what I'm doing wrong, please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the last sentence is "At the bottom of the xslt file starting with <xsl:template match="main_image"> is the beginning of my attempt to display one of my images" Thank you!

Comment: Please post your code **as code** within your question - not as pictures in links. Also show the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to transform XML to HTML, in HTML to display images you use the `img` element with a `src` attribute. So use e.g. `<img src="{@file}"/>` in XSLT in a template with `match="main_image"` to create an HTML `img` result element where the `src` attribute takes as the value the `file` attribute of a `main_image` element in the input XML.